# Heroku deployment issue with Socket.io....404 not found. Namespace issue?

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I`ve looked over a lot of the Stack pages and can't find the solution despite trying many variations.

I`m creating a multiplayer game with socket.io and express within react. Utilising the namespace feature of socket.io.

My code works in the local environment and I am able to populate namespace rooms for users to connect to and play a game. However I uploaded to heroku and now I receive:

`=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MrVg7lq" host=myherokudomain.com`

from the server, so my connection is hitting but it is not finding the requisite room.

The server code looks like:

```
const app = express();

app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));

app.use(express.json());

const server = app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('server is running on port 8080');
});

io = socket(server);

// ROOM 1

const room1 = io.of('/room1');

room1.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.emit('RECEIVE_MESSAGE', { author: 'Server', message: 'Hi you are connected!' });
});
```

In the index.js on the server side I have the following setup partly for the database:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = require('./src/app');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_CONN, { useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001);
});
```

On the client side I have the following:

```
this.socket = io('https://myherokudomain.com/room1');
```

Where am I going wrong? It has taken me two days to puzzle this through and I am no further forward.

Any questions please ask and any help, gratefully received!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku set-up automatically ports.

**Try**

```
const server = app.listen(8080 || process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log('server is running on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have implemented it but no joy.

Comment: Actually mate you kind of ended up helping me. Because I realised I was in fact running two instances of app.listen! Thank you for making me think about this.